# Argument Out of Range Exception was unhandled

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, outofrangeexception

I have below piece of code which runs fine only except when the last index of Combobox is reached it gives the error as mentioned in Title. More details:
Invalid Argument=Value of '17' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex

The code runs through all the indices available in the Combo-box and gives the desired output. But when the last value is reached I get this error. 
Could someone please guide me?

```
Private Sub ExportButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportButton.Click

        Dim LastItem As Integer = 0
        LastItem = TagComboBox1.Items.Count

        For i As Integer = 0 To LastItem

            TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i

         'CODE to perform some operation..

            If TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = LastItem Then
                 Exit For
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Count` returns the *number* of elements **not** the highest element *index* so you need to take 1 off it in your loop:

```
LastItem = TagComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

See the documentation for this information: [ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Count Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Matt.. truly Appreciate your quick response. It worked great and solved my problem. Thanks again.